# Up to date, extensive documentary about dinosaurs?

Tags: evolution, palaeontology

I just finished reading the [Wikipedia page about dinosaurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur), and I very much enjoyed it. I knew that much of what I learned in the 80's as a child is (and was) incorrect, and now that I am a parent, I am excited to finally make some time to learn about this stuff.

It seems that a lot is known about ecosystems, socialization, and interactions between different species, herd behavior, and other interesting things.

Before I start reading books, I want to watch a good documentary.  A quick google search turned up some suggested documentaries, but in general they seem to be either old or focused on a particular dinosaur, and not on the era in particular.  All are short.

I watched [the 10 hour documentary "The Life of Mammals" by David Attenborough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_of_Mammals) a few years ago, and developed a much better understanding of how we as humans evolved, and how we are related to other mammals. I'd love it if there was something as extensive about Triassic/Jurassic/Cretaceous era dinosaurs. Is there something recent, extensive, and mostly correct?

Comment: Doesn't have to be in English either

Comment: David Attenborough I stay away from. Since his Aquatic Ape hypothesis. Do read books - and until you do check out the work of a much more modern and better educated evolutionary biologist, Neil Shubin, who discovered Tiktaalik and wrote the Your Inner Fish book. There's a three-part documentary, Your Inner Fish - Monkey - Reptile. http://video.pbs.org/program/your-inner-fish/ Now that's a serious documentary by a scientist. The dinosaur documentaries are usually for kids, and are usually very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try *Planet Dinosaur* (2011) or *Dinosaur Revolution* (2011). Neither is as good as the original *Walking with Dinosaurs* trilogy, but both are relatively informative and entertaining at the same time.